# Point of menu tag if not supported by all major browsers

Tags: html, web

I was wondering this while I was learning some front-end web development. But does anyone understand what the point of the menu tag is for html if the tag is not supported in all major browsers?  When I was inspecting some web page I saw its use then looked on the w3schools website for more info about it, and it states that there its not supported in any browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case:

The `menu` element was introduced in HTML 3.2, did not see wide take up from browser authors, was deprecated in HTML 4 and removed in HTML 5.

It has no place on the modern web.

---

In more general terms:

Most features of web standards have limited support from browsers when they are first introduced. Often their effects can be replicated in browsers that do not support them using CSS and/or JavaScript.

Sometimes take up of a feature is so poor that it gets removed from the standards again (although modern approaches to writing standards mean they will tend to live in a draft state until it is clear if the support is going to be good enough).

It is up to the page author to decide when there is sufficient client support for a feature for it to be worth using, and how much effort they wish to go to in order to make it work in older browsers.